# how to check whether data is available on socket?

Tags: c, windows, api, sockets

```
SOCKET s;   // Create a SOCKET for listening for
            // incoming connection requests.
SOCKET new_socket;  // create a socket for accepting incoming connection
uint16 port =18001;


void CreateSocket()
{
    int sin_size;   
    WSADATA wsa;
        struct sockaddr_in server, master;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number


            printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
        {
            printf("Failed Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Initialised\n");


        //CREATING a SOCKET

        if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        {
            printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
            //return 0;
        }
        printf("Socket Created\n");

        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;     
        server.sin_port = htons(port); 


        //Binding between the socket and ip address

        if(bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        puts("Bind Done");


        //Listen to incoming connections
        listen(s, 3);


        //Accepting the incoming connection


                    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

            new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&master, &sin_size);

            printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)",
                   inet_ntoa(master.sin_addr),ntohs(master.sin_port));
            closesocket(new_socket);


            /*new_socket = accept(s, NULL, NULL);

           if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
           {
        printf("accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(new_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } 
           else
        printf("Client connected.\n");*/
}
```

I have created the socket and accepting the connection from the master but anyone tell me the condition for checking if there is any data available on the specified port number ?? I am using windows operating system. The above code is for creating socket for windows operating system.

how to make the above code to accept port number as an argument for sending and receiving data ??

Comment: What socket api are you using - winsock? Please be more specific, and if you created a socket please post your code to help with answering your question.

Comment: I have edited my code and also added one extra question .

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find this online.

Assuming you are using winsock API, you just need to call `recvfrom()` - it will either return an error if there is some problem, or it will block until there is available incoming data.

See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This does not help with checking if there's data without blocking.